# Creating a static field in header file | C++

Tags: c++, static, field

I am working on an assignment, and while I don't have any issues with the actual assignment, I want to make my code "proper." I am trying to define a static variable in my header file. I want it to be static so that all instances of this class can access the same variable. I don't want to extern it either, I want just this class to have access to it.Then I am trying to define it in the actual file (not header) but I keep getting an error about not being able to cast. I just want to learn how to properly do this to have cleaner code.

[image]

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide [code people can use to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: And the code must be in text format in the question not an image.

Comment: In the implementation (.cc) file you need to properly declare your variable, not just assign to it. E.g `List* AddrSpace::availSlots = new List();`

Comment: I'd like to help, but firewalls are blocking access to your link site.  How about if you **edit** your post with the *text* of your code?

Answer (score 1):

The definition of your field stays inside the class:

```
class AddrSpace
{
    List *availSpots;
};
```

The full name of this variable will be `AddrSpace::availSpots`. C++ requires to define static variables (including the static fields of the classes) explicitly. I would not say this is fully logical because compiler already has everything to generate all necessary stuffs. Nevertheless this is so. The definition in your C++ file should look like:

```
List *AddrSpace::availSpots = new List();
```

Next time please add the source directly into the question.